# i have this error java.lang.Error: SWT Resource was not properly disposed while building Swing application

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, memory-leaks, jvisualvm

i have this error java.lang.Error: SWT Resource was not properly disposed while building Swing application - i saw it  when monitor it by visualvm.exe -when get heapdump and open it by eclipse MAT and this makes memory leak

```
java.lang.Error: SWT Resource was not properly disposed
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.initNonDisposeTracking(Resource.java:172)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Resource.<init>(Resource.java:120)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Region.<init>(Region.java:63)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.swt.RegionAction.<init>(RegionAction.java:248)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.device.swt.SwtRendererImpl.enableInteraction(SwtRendererImpl.java:1331)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.extension.render.PieRenderer$PieSlice.render(PieRenderer.java:3523)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.extension.render.PieRenderer$PieSlice.access$9(PieRenderer.java:3217)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.extension.render.PieRenderer.render(PieRenderer.java:1791)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.extension.render.Pie.renderSeries(Pie.java:196)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.render.BaseRenderer.renderPlot(BaseRenderer.java:1833)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.render.BaseRenderer.render(BaseRenderer.java:476)
at org.eclipse.birt.chart.factory.Generator.render(Generator.java:1382)
at org.eclipse.mat.ui.internal.chart.ChartCanvas.drawToCachedImage(ChartCanvas.java:156)
at org.eclipse.mat.ui.internal.chart.ChartCanvas.access$2(ChartCanvas.java:139)
at org.eclipse.mat.ui.internal.chart.ChartCanvas$1.paintControl(ChartCanvas.java:83)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4243)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1063)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1087)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1072)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PAINT(Composite.java:1627)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4803)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3630)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

Comment: Something (probably Eclipse Birt) is not disposing of SWT resources properly. That is all that can be said from the stack trace.